# Why are all the rows in the table from MySQL are the same? (MySQL Table > HTML Table)

Tags: html, mysql, html-table, row

I am trying to take all the rows in MySQL table and put them in the HTML table:

```html
<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <td>Exam ID</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>Assigned Examiner</td>
        <td>Recruit's name</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `access`");
        $num = mysql_num_rows($query);
        $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    ?>
    <?php for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++) { ?>
    <tr>
    <?php echo '<td>' . $r['code'] . '</td>'; } ?> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

And it outputs like:

```
Exam ID <br />
1<br />
1<br />
1<br />
```

And obviously, I want it to be like in the MySQL where it's increasing.

Answer (score 2):

You're only fetching the first row.

Put `mysql_fetch_assoc` in the loop :

```
                <?php for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++) { 
                $r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                ?>
                <tr>
                <?php echo '<td>' . $r['code'] . '</td>'; } ?> 
                </tr>
```

Note that there are more recent functions to use (see [the warning in the doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a while loop:

```
<tr>
<?php 
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query){

    echo '<td>' . $r['code'] . '</td>';

}
?>
</tr>
```

Also note that `mysql_` php commands are being depreciated soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <td>Exam ID</td>
        <td>Status</td>
        <td>Assigned Examiner</td>
        <td>Recruit's name</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        // The query
        $query = 'SELECT exam_id, status, examine_name, recruiter_name FROM access';

        // The counter
        $number_of_rows = 0;

        //Run, Fetch and print
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT exam_id, status, examine_name, recruiter_name FROM access');
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach($column as $column_name => $column_value){
                printf('<td>%s</td>', $column_value);
            }
            echo '</tr>';
            $number_of_rows++;
        }
    ?>
</table>

<p class="information">
    <?php printf('The query returned %d rows.', $number_of_rows);?>
</p>
```